# How can I get the domain of a fraction under a square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can find the domain of a fraction function under a square root through drawing the function on graph. Yet, I seem to not be able to find it algebrically.
To be precise, I want to find the domain of this function:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+1/x}$$
Thank you.

Comment: For what real numbers $a$ exist $\sqrt{a}$? Can you divide by zero?

Comment: What are the restrictions your function have? What is under the square root must be positive, you can't divide by zero. These two restrictions give two sets of numbers on which your function is defined. So, take the intersection of these two sets to find the desired domain.

Comment: Also, these spoonfeeding answers disgust me. No effort was shown from the OP.

Comment: @Math_QED on questions like this what kind of effort do you expect?  Personally, I think answers which point the way and use as little "math notation" as possible are best because if the OP was able to read and understand the math notation (like what they would see in their textbook) then they wouldn't need to ask the question.  "Spoon feeding" as you call it may just be answering the question in a manner that the OP can understand instead of using math double-speak.

Comment: I'd like to know what the OP has tried with algebra. I'm sure the OP has made such exercises in class.

Comment: I'm still a first-year college student, and yes we've done even harder exercises in class. I know the restriction and I know the basic steps of how to get a domain of course. But in this example I just missed a simple point that made me go very confused and it wasn't really described well in my textbook.
I am still at a very low level and I am aware of that, and understanding simple questions (for you) like these really help me a lot.
I apologize for my lack of information.

Answer (score 4):

I usually start by assuming the domain is all real numbers, then removing the values of $x$ that don't make sense.  What remains is the domain.  In your case, if $x=0$ then you are dividing by zero.  That's bad, so remove $x=0$ from the domain.  What else can go wrong?  Taking the square root of a negative number will cause problems (unless you're working in the complex numbers).  So figure out when is $1 + \frac{1}{x} < 0$.  All those values of $x$ are not in the domain.

Comment: But when I do this, I get x<-1 and these values are actually in the domain.
What am I missing here?

Comment: @AbdallahElsharnouby Be careful when you multiply or divide by $x$... if $x$ is negative the inequality will flip.  It is pretty easy to see that if $x>0$ then then $1+\frac{1}{x} > 0$ too...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Basically, the conditions are
$$x\ne 0\quad\text{and}\quad 1+\frac 1x=\frac{x+1}x\ge 0. $$
Now the sign of the fraction is the sign of the product $x(x+1)$, and you have a theorem about the sign of a quadratic polynomial…

Answer (score 0):

When working with real numbers, you can't take a square root of a negative number. So we need whatever is under the square root to be $\geq 0$. Start there and then manipulate.

In your example:

(First note that since a $\frac{1}{x}$ appears, $x \neq 0$)

$1 + \frac{1}{x} \geq 0$

$\frac{1}{x} \geq -1$

Now if $x$ is positive this always holds. If $x$ is negative, then we get:

$1 \leq -x$

$x \leq -1$

So the domain is $(-\infty, -1] \cup (0, \infty)$